# How to release memory?

Tags: c++, qt

I have Created a simple QT application for my university assignment.  What i have done is  pop up a new QManinWindow from a Above QMainWindow. When i click a button from the main ui it will pop up a new QMainWindow object (Note Pad)

Note pad is also a QMainWindow object

My Problem is when I'm creating the object it takes some memory from the ram but when I'm closing it (pop up window) memory is not  releasing. When each time I'm pressing a button memory is allocated but application does not relese the memory when im closing it. Please check the main screen of the app.

i just want to know how to release that memory. I have tried so many things but nothing worked well.

I have set the closeEvent public on NotePad class and I listen the close event from main object when its get triggered i have deleted the poped up object. But it cause ad unexpected stop.

```
void MainWindow::on_notePadBtn_clicked()
{

    NotePad *notePad = new NotePad(this);
    notePad->raise();
    notePad->activateWindow();
    notePad->show();
}


NotePad::NotePad(QWidget *parent) :QMainWindow(parent),ui(new Ui::NotePad) {

    ui->setupUi(this);
    this->setWindowTitle("Note Pad");
}
```

Comment: In the closeEvent, you should use `notePad->deleteLater()` instead of `delete notePad`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need to override `closeEvent`, Qt has [Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WidgetAttribute-enum) attribute, that does exactly what you want, you can use it like this:

```
//...
NotePad *notePad = new NotePad(this);
notePad->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
notePad->raise();
notePad->activateWindow();
notePad->show();
//...
```

Answer (score -2):

I'm not familiar with Qt.

But to my understanding if you use the operator new
you must use `delete` (in a scope where you have access to the pointer created with new).

```
Object *foo = new Object();
// Do stuff with foo...
delete foo;
// DO NOT use foo from now on.
```

Hope that helps a bit, maybe. Like I said I'm not familiar with Qt 
so if you have doubts about how some features are implemented you should look at the their docs.

(cf: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf §3.7.4p63)

Comment: This answer will not help the situation. You don't want to delete the window object int the `on_notePadBtn_clicked()` function because that will be before you want it to close.

Comment: Um. I'm glad you mention that. In C++ you use delete when you use new. like I said I'm not familiar with Qt but if it makes you use new without delete that's just terrible. There are many ways to avoid making the user do that if they have custom functions to take care of it. I don't get it. Anyway. Thanks for correcting me